# Elasticsearch: multiple word synonims does not affect score in query

Tags: elasticsearch

ES newbie here, looking for help in understanding what's wrong.

Let's consider this index mapping, where I define some synonims for motobike models :

```
   {
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "replace": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "&=> and "
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "word_delimiter": {
          "type": "word_delimiter",
          "split_on_numerics": "false",
          "split_on_case_change": "true",
          "generate_word_parts": "true",
          "generate_number_parts": "true",
          "catenate_all": "true",
          "preserve_original": "true",
          "catenate_numbers": "true"
        },
        "custom_synonym": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "lenient": "true",
          "synonyms": [
            "r 1200 r , r1200 r, r 1200r, r1200r",
            "r 1150 r, r1150 r, r 1150r, r 1150 r, r1150r"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip",
            "replace"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "custom_synonym",
            "lowercase",
            "word_delimiter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "pname": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "default"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I put two documents in the index :

```
PUT test_index/product/1
{
  "pname" : "MOTORBIKE BMW R 1150 R"
}


PUT test_index/product/2
{
  "pname" : "MOTORBIKE BMW R 1200 R"
}
```

And then perform a match query like :

```
GET test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "pname" : "MOTORBIKE R1200R"
        }
    }
}
```

I get both hits with the same score :

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "product",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "pname" : "MOTORBIKE BMW R 1200 R"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "product",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "pname" : "MOTORBIKE BMW R 1150 R"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My expectation was to have a bigger score on the "MOTORBIKE BMW R 1200 R" document  since I have defined a synonim for the "r1200r" term : ( r 1200 r , r1200 r, r 1200r, r1200r ).

Any clue ?

Comment: First of all, you should probably move the lowercase filter in front of the custom_synonym - the order is relevant in your analyzer definition! Additionally, you can always check what your analyzer actually does to a sentence: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html

Comment: Thank you. The problem appear to be that a synonim is getting tokenized by whitespace itself, so a synonim like "r 1200 r" is getting tokenized in r,1200,r , where it should be threated as a single sentence to suit my case. Is there a way to avoid this happening during index time ?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Synonyms are tokenized just the same way as any value or query on the field. And that is needed for multi-term synonyms anyway. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/synonyms-analysis-chain.html
Just make sure that if you analyze a synonym it should result in the same outcome as if you analyze the search term.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did some more tests and figured up that my synonims should be threated as **keyword** at index time , in order to have ie. a single token for "r 1200 r" as "r1200r" synonim instead of three tokens "r, 1200, r", so I made a dedicated analyzer for this that is working well when checking the synonim terms, but I'm struggling how can I obtain a match query for a "r1200r" query (that should be translated with its synonim "r 1200 r") against a complete document field like "MY MOTORBIKE IS A R 1200 R" ... I always get inconsistant results or wrong score...

Answer (score 1):

I finally had time to do some tests with your examples. I try to explain as much as possible, let me point out 2 things I changed to make it work:

1) in your settings, change the analyzer to:

```
"analyzer": {
    "default": {
      "type": "custom",
      "char_filter": [
        "html_strip",
        "replace"
      ],
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "word_delimiter",
        "custom_synonym"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Look at the filter section. As I said, the order matters. You want to lowercase first, and then tokenize (before applying synonyms). That's probably what caused confusion about tokens. Synonyms are tokenized too, actually. If you analyze your synonym ("r 1200 r" as an example) with this analyzer, the output is rather overwhelming. I try to make an example, where i describe tokens with their position in the index: [token](position):

indexing "r 1200 r" will index the following 'tree':

- [r](0) [1200](1) [r](2) - original / synonym variant 1
- [r1200](0) [r](1) - synonym variant 2
- [r](0) [1200r](1) - synonym variant 3
- [r1200r](0) - synonym variant 4

This is, because the way you defined your synonyms means, elasticsearch expands and will index all possible combinations you defined. You can also see, that an actual search for 'r' will yield results, because r simply is a token - even when indexing r1200r.

2) Now, I don't think that's what you want, so I changed the synonym definition to a contraction style notation:

```
"custom_synonym": {
  "type": "synonym",
  "lenient": "true",
  "synonyms": [
    "r 1200 r , r1200 r, r 1200r => r1200r",
    "r 1150 r, r1150 r, r 1150r, r 1150 r => r1150r"
  ]
}
```

Which basically transforms tokens [r][1200][r] etc. and only indexes the term to the right of the arrow: r1200r. Please read the following article for more information - the whole thing is rather complicated and one needs to think a lot about what expected behavior is desired: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/synonyms-expand-or-contract.html

But, with this definition, searches for 'r' alone will no longer yield any results. And, searching for "MOTORBIKE R1200R" should always return the document with id 2 on top. And it should not matter if it's "motorbike r 1200r" or any variation, the score should remain the same.

Note however, with this solution, searching for 1200 or 1150 alone will not return any match, since 1200 is never an indexed term when processed by the synonym filter. (exception of course if you only index "bla bla 1200" for example, since the synonyms will not match on that.

Synonyms, especially multi-term synonyms are rather hard to deal with. I know I am a bit obnoxious about linking the documentation, but it is worth to read the whole chapter incl. subchapters of https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/synonyms.html

Nevertheless, if you have specific questions to my answer, feel free to comment. If I have time I will try to update and clarify my answer.

Comment: Well , thank you for your time ! Your response is super-clear - I'm going to experiment :)

Comment: Altough your suggestion improved my queries a lot, I still have a "use case" that I am unable to fix. Let's keep our example valid (with your correct modifications to mapping and contraction style) - Add a simple synonim "carbon wheels => carbon rims" and three documents "CARBON FRAME MOTORCYCLE", "ALLOY RIMS MOTORCYCLE", "CARBON WHEELS DISCOUNTED". Now launch a match query for "carbon rims" - You'll see first result "ALLOY RIMS MOTORCYCLE" with a better score than "CARBON WHEELS DISCOUNTED" - My expectation was to have "CARBON WHEELS DISCOUNTED" at first place because of the new synonim.

Comment: Try using explain to understand where the score comes from: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html Based on your comment, I can't really say what the problem is. Maybe it's better to open a new question with posted mapping/settings/explanation.